# Repository pattern and/or/vs business logic layer

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a problem I want to know your opinion.

I am trying to use Repository Pattern. I have a repository object which load data to a POCO. I have also created a Business logic layer which adds a little bit of functionality but basically wraps the POCO. So in the end I have a BLL which loads DAO with usage of repository.

I am not very happy with this solution. I have a three layers but I feel that BLL is not providing enought functionality to keep it there. On the other hand I do not want to put my logic in the repository layer nor data access layer?

So my question is where should I put logic for application? Which solution do you use(DAO + repo or DAO + BLL + rep or any other)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two basic ways to think about business rules when designing your domain.

1.) The domain entities are basic POCO/[DTO](http://www.google.com/search?q=data+transfer+object)s. And you hand them off to domain services. These services could be as simple as another class, or they really could be actual services sitting on another server.

```
var user = repository.Find(x => x.UserName == userName);
if (userLogonService.IsValidUser(user, password)) {
   userLogonService.UpdateUserAsLoggedOn(user);
}
repository.SaveChanges();
```

2.) The domain entities contain their own operation logic. This is closer to what many MVC patterns will follow. *And since you asked, this is the model that I prefer.*

```
var user = repository.Find(x => x.UserName == userName);
if (user.CheckPassword(password)) {
    user.LogOnNow();
}
repository.SaveChanges();
```

Both are completely valid patterns. #1 has a discrete business operation tier, but suffers from an [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.google.com/search?q=anemic+domain+model). #2 can lead to big domain entities if you domain starts to become complicated, or if a model can do a lot of things.

### EDIT #1: Response to John Kraft

> Oven.Bake(myPizza) vs. myPizza.Bake()

I mostly agree. Do you have a single Oven service, or do you have dozens of available ovens stored in an oven repository where oven is just another domain entity? In #2, the oven is part of the domain. The way I tend to do domain modeling, **most nouns are domain entities**, unless you are 100% sure that there is exactly one of the thing.

But something does happen to pizza when it is baked.

```
interface ICanBeBaked {
    int BakeMinutes { get; }
    int BakeTemp { get; }
    void Bake();
}
class Pizza : ICanBeBaked {
    int BakeMinutes { get { return 15; } }
    int BakeTemp { get { return 425; } }
    void Bake() {
        // melt cheese!
        this.isBaked = true;
    }
}
class Oven {
    void Bake(ICanBeBaked thingToBake) {
        // set the temp, reserve this oven for the duration, etc.
        thingToBake.Bake();
    }
}
```

Comment: the #2 is sth I want to avoid, but I feel that putting a lot of logic into BLL and using business object to wrap a POCO/DAO is not a best solution. I have no idea why I have not though about services layer.

I suppose that in a case the domain grows big there is no easy and nice way to separate all logic, so this have to be considered at the stage of design.

Comment: I prefer option #1 to #2. I equate these to an example:
#1 =>  Oven.Bake(myPizza)
#2 =>  myPizza.Bake()

#2 just feelse wrong to me because pizza's just don't do anything in the real world.

Comment: One drawback I see to approach #2 is that now the domain object is no longer just a value object (POCO) it contains logic aswell. So it is going to make it difficult to move across service boundaries and that means creating seperate DTO's. Personally I prefer to externalize the logic from the domain objects via domain services. That way the logic can be tested independently of the persistence (SRP principle).

Comment: Go back and read Evans' Domain Driven Design. It is very noun/verb oriented. Your entities should do things. There's a difference between DTO's and entities. DTO != POCO. POCO means that it doesn't rely on any part of the framework (No calls to DB, servers, queues, files, etc. Logic is self-encapsulated.) In DDD, value objects are not entities. And in DDD, your entities have logic.

Comment: In #1, we should reference to both of the Repository and Services layers from UI. is it correct? Then it might confuses the developers about where they should use the Repository or Service methods. The same problem exists about where they should put their queries (in the services or repository?). Please help me in this regard.

Comment: More over, Can the service layer use the repository directly? for example we give an ID to the "userLogonService.UpdateUserAsLoggedOn" method and it gets the user from repository. Is it correct?

Comment: Isn't it #1 that has the discrete business operation tier, but suffers from an Anemic Domain Model while #2 that can lead to big domain entities?

Comment: @Colin Yes, putting methods on your domain entities can lead to large domain entities. This is especially true when there's lot of things that can happen to an object.

Comment: Thought so. Just that your answer actually says the opposite!

Comment: @JarrettMeyer What about encapsulation? Can you answer this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/207881/encapsulation-in-domain-driven-design-models

Answer (score 2):

My "DAL" (more of a home-grown ORM, which is another topic) is really a couple of layers in itself; one abstraction that provides repository and some active record pattern support, and below that is the actual data access code.

We have a minimal business layer at this point, but the real reason is that it's thin is that there's way too much (legacy) business logic embedded in web page code-behinds. As that gets refactored, I expect the business layer to grow and grow and grow.

This is fairly standard layering. You don't say why you're unhappy with your current stack, but keep in mind that the core reason for doing this is separation of responsibilities. You might also want to take a look at concepts of Domain Driven Design; it provides lots of food for thought for organizing code around business policies and practices, rather than specifically software issues. It's a very useful analytical tool to have in your toolbox.