# Business logic in repositories or in separate business classes?

Tags: architecture, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, business-logic

I’m developing an application where I’m using repositories (repository pattern) that handle all the CRUD operations (I’m using entity framework) and Unit of work for handling the context.
I have a generic repository like this:

```
Public Interface IRepository(Of TEntity As Class)

 Function GetAll() As IEnumerable(Of TEntity)
 Function GetByID(id As Object) As TEntity

End Interface


Public Class Repository(Of TEntity As Class)
  Implements IRepository(Of TEntity)

  Friend _dbContext As Entities = Nothing
  Friend _dbSet As IDbSet(Of TEntity)

  Public Sub New(ByVal context As Entities)
    If context Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("context wasn't supplied")
    End If
    Me._dbContext = context
    Me._dbSet = context.Set(Of TEntity)()
  End Sub

  Public Function GetAll() As IEnumerable(Of TEntity) Implements IRepository(Of TEntity).GetAll
    Return _dbSet.ToList().AsQueryable()
 End Function



 Public Overridable Function GetByID(id As Object) As TEntity Implements IRepository(Of     
    TEntity).GetByID
    Return _dbSet.Find(id)
 End Function


End Class


Public Interface IUnitOfWork

  ReadOnly Property PersonRepository() As IRepository(Of Person)
  ReadOnly Property OrgRepository() As IRepository(Of Organization)

  Sub Save()

End Interface


Public Class UnitOfWork
Implements IUnitOfWork
Implements IDisposable

Private _context As Entities
Private _personRepository As IRepository(Of Person)
Private _orgRepository As IRepository(Of Organization)
Private disposed As Boolean = False

Public Sub New()
    Me._context = New Entities
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property PersonRepository() As IRepository(Of Person) Implements  IUnitOfWork.PersonRepository
    Get
        If Me._personRepository Is Nothing Then
            Me._personRepository = New Repository(Of Person)(_context)
        End If
        Return _personRepository
    End Get
End Property

.
.
.
.

Public Sub Save() Implements IUnitOfWork.Save
    _context.SaveChanges()
End Sub

Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub

Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposed Then
        If disposing Then
            _context.Dispose()
        End If
    End If
    Me.disposed = True
End Sub

End Class
```

My problem is the business logic, where should I put it? I need to count up all my persons returned and I have to calculate the total weight of all these persons. Should this be done in the person repository or do I need a separate person class for this?
This is not a MVC application, my classes should be used by another application (I have no front end classes).

I have looked at [this example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Under the headline “Changing the Course Controller to use the UnitOfWork Class and Repositories” he does this

```
public ViewResult Details(int id) { 
  Course course = unitOfWork.CourseRepository.GetByID(id); 
  return View(course); 
 }
```

How is it possible to say

```
Course course = unitOfWork.CourseRepository.GetByID(id);
```

The course object is of type Course but the object returned from unitOfWork.CourseRepository.GetByID(id) is of type course entity (from entity framework).

My last question….can I have any properties in the repository classes. If I should have my function for counting all the people and my total weight function in the repository class I need to also have my properties for name, address and so on for storing information.

I hope sombody can help me :)

Thanks in advance!

Liss

EDIT:

Thanks for your answer! So what you are saying is that if I don't have any heavy logic (that is the case for me) I use an extra Person class where I have my properties an also functions for weight and total number of person, but also functions that "mirrors" the functions (GetAll, GetByID) in the generic repository class. And I use the Person class from other classes not the repository class? I still don't understand the example Course course = unitOfWork.CourseRepository.GetByID(id), her the repository and unit of work is used the same way as I did, I think. But when I try this, the unitOfWork.CourseRepository.GetByID(id) returns an object of entity type but the course is an "ordinary" object type (a ordinary class with only properties). How can I say: object of type A = object of type B?

EDIT 2:

Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer me!! So what you say is that it is sometimes better to not auto generate entities but write POCO class instead? But if I want to use my auto generated entities, and I have an entity named PersonEntity I can use this like this in my controller class like this:

```
 Dim personEntity As PersonEntity

 personEntity = unitOfWork.PersonEntityRepository.GetByID(id)
```

But if I do it like this I have a reference to an entity in my controller class, but do I want that? Isn’t it best to separate the entities from the controller if I later need to change from Entity Framework? 
But what I still do not understand is, should I create a new Person class with the same properties as the autogen PersonEntity class and use this in my controller like this

```
Dim person As Person

person = unitOfWork.PersonEntityRepository.GetByID(id)
```

But then the unitOfWork.PersonEntityRepository.GetByID(id) will return a object of type PersonEntity… so this is not working.
And where should I put my total weight and total persons functions?

If I understand what you are saying, an entity object can be used as a transfer object but it’s better to use a POCO/DTO object. But if I use a Person POCO can I still have the PersonEntity object? And how do I populate the POCO object when I return the PersonEntity object?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "where should I put business logic": There are two approaches:

1. Complex business logic usually goes into a service layer. A service may depend on one or more repositories to perform CRUD operations on your models. Thus a single service operation representing a business operation may depend on multiple simple operations. Then you could reuse this service layer in your controllers and other applications. Use basic POCO/DTOs for data transfer between layers.
2. Use domain entities which contain their own operation logic.

A similar discussion can be found here so please have a look on:
[Repository pattern and/or/vs business logic layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484193/repository-pattern-and-or-vs-business-logic-layer)

And about the example you mentioned which is using

```
"Course course = unitOfWork.CourseRepository.GetByID(id);"
```

It is very possible as we can compose the Repository and UoW Patterns in different ways. Please have a look on
this question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151374/relationship-between-repository-and-unit-of-work

and an answer by Wouter de Kort here
[Entity Framework + Repository + Unit of Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722039/entity-framework-repository-unit-of-work)

Yes, you can have properties instead of get methods. I prefer get methods as it gives better uniformity to use a repository.

Hope it would be helpful. Please let me know in case of further questions. Thanks.

**Additional Answers after your edit:**

You are  Welcome. I have downloaded that code for the example and looked again to understand your query but I can see that: both side of the line :"Course course = unitOfWork.CourseRepository.GetByID(id);" refers to same class :ContosoUniversity.Models.Course.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Course course = unitOfWork.CourseRepository.GetByID(id);
        PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(course.DepartmentID);
        return View(course);
    }
```

The code inside following "Details" method of CourseController does not have the same code as shown in the webpage:
    public ActionResult Details(int id)

Further you can have Person class as a Model class having business logic related to Person inside class. And PersonRepository would have methods like (GetAll, GetByID). If you have many repositories you can create a GenericRepository too as given below:

```
class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

I hope its fine by now. Further questions are most welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I have edited my post, if you have time to take a look?!

Comment: I have downloaded that code for the example page and looked again to understand your query but I can see that: both side of the line :"Course course = unitOfWork.CourseRepository.GetByID(id);" refers to same class :ContosoUniversity.Models.Course. I can not get what u are referring by writing "How can I say: object of type A = object of type B?" in your recent edit.

Comment: I have also edited my answer which include the message in upper comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again. The Course, Department, Instructor..... classes are the same as my Person and Organization classes auto generated from Entity framework? Sorry, but I have forgotten to say that I'm using EF and have auto generated classes and a generic repository on top. Do I need autogen entity classes, and a generic repository class on top, and another personservice/ordinary person class on top of that again? I feel like it is too many classes… I cannot manage to understand how all of this fit together. Sorry, I hope it is not too many questions!

Comment: I like more questions coming up. Thanks. There is no need to create new classes because you can extend the generated classes of EF. Please have a look on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. This page says: "The ADO.NET Entity Framework includes a tool that, given an EDM schema, will generate the .NET classes that represent the EDM entities inside the .NET environment. The generated classes are partial classes, so they can be extended with custom business logic in separate files without interfering with the code generator."

Comment: Thanks again! But if I extend my entity classes and use them in let say my controller class (if I was developing an MVC application), wouldn't that be wrong. I thought some of the purpose of using repository is to separate the entities from the upper layers?

Comment: Repository pattern does not have that purpose, it decouple the data access logic from the application. It provides an abstraction over the data source. For example, the data source layer can be a database, a SharePoint list, or a Web service.
For a big application having multiple layers, its better to use POCO or DTO to transfer the data among layers. Obviously entities are not better choice as they are heavy in comparison to POCO or DTO.  For small and medium size application we can use entities if it is not so performance sensitive. To send data to View, you would be using ViewModels.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! If you still can take the time to help me can you please take a look at my EDIT 2?

Comment: In that case, Create a PersonRepository (not PersonEntityRepository) and call it like unitOfWork.PersonRepository.GetByID(id)....it will return a Person Object only. Use Entities inside method GetByID with appropriate logic. In future if entities or data source changes only you need to modify the logic inside method GetByID. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, but the "most common" way is to use the autogen entities also in the controller like this: Dim personEntity As PersonEntity personEntity = unitOfWork.PersonEntityRepository.GetByID(id) and use a PersonEntityRepository? But where do I put the logic for totalWeight and totalNumberOfPersons?

Comment: As I wrote earlier, you can extend the generated classes of EF. Please have a look on msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. This page says: "The ADO.NET Entity Framework includes a tool that, given an EDM schema, will generate the .NET classes that represent the EDM entities inside the .NET environment. The generated classes are partial classes, so they can be extended with custom business logic in separate files without interfering with the code generator." Thanks.